# MySql 'show engine innodb status' truncating queries in output. (Attempting to solve Deadlock issues)

Tags: sql, mysql, database-deadlocks

I have been trying to solve some MySQL deadlock issues using `show engine innodb status`.
Our platform uses Google's Cloud SQL and the offending SQL queries in the Innodb Monitor is truncating the queries to only 903 characters. Circa 2016 there was a bug that truncated the  report to 1024 characters, but this was resolved https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80927. I am using Hibernate ORM so the queries can be quite long.

Any thoughts as to how I can fix this or obtain the query data another way?

*Some data from the excerpts have been omitted as to not publish protected data (passwords, etc).*

**Query Excerpts from the Innodb Monitor**

1st Transaction Query: 903 characters

```
update AppUser set Address1='919 Conference Drive #4285', AgentPortalAccessToken=null, AgentPortalAccessTokenExpires=null, AgentPortalActive=0, AgentPortalKeySecret=null, AgentPortalLastLoginDateTime=null, AppUserType='NORMAL', AutoDialerPhone=null, BrokerName='', BrokerNum='Dotted & Crossed', City='Goodlettsville', Email1='[.. OMIT ...]', Fax='', FirstName='Paige', ICalFeedAccessKey='[.. OMIT ...]', IsActive=1, LastLoginDateTime='2023-10-20 13:39:49', LastName='Collier', LicenseNum='', LogoFileName='6664cfd4-c435-4c80-b29a-e63853f1fb84.png', Mobile='[.. OMIT ...]', PasswordChangeRequired=0, PasswordHash='[.. OMIT ...]', PasswordResetKey=null, PasswordResetKeyExpires=null, PayableTo='Dotted & Crossed', Phone1='[.. OMIT ...]', ProfileFileName='7dadd45c-9b41-46e9-a944-e740b0c1043e.jpg', RelationshipLeadTime_
```

2nd Transaction Query: 903 characters

```
update AppUser set Address1='1500 Medical Center Parkway suite 2e', AgentPortalAccessToken='946131', AgentPortalAccessTokenExpires='2023-08-04 15:03:45', AgentPortalActive=1, AgentPortalKeySecret='[.. OMIT ...]', AgentPortalLastLoginDateTime=null, AppUserType='NO_LOGIN', AutoDialerPhone=null, BrokerName='Zach Taylor', BrokerNum='265048', City='Murfreesboro', Email1='[.. OMIT ...]', Fax='', FirstName='Hannah', ICalFeedAccessKey='[.. OMIT ...]', IsActive=1, LastLoginDateTime='2023-08-04 14:53:57', LastName='Mazzaferro', LicenseNum='354478', LogoFileName='b6f94afa-16d8-4e03-a555-38c2ee7df042.png', Mobile='[.. OMIT ...]', PasswordChangeRequired=0, PasswordHash='[.. OMIT ...]', PasswordResetKey=null, PasswordResetKeyExpires=null, PayableTo='Zach Taylor', Phone1='[.. OMIT ...]', ProfileFileName=
```

**Full Innodb Monitor Output**

```
=====================================
2023-10-20 14:31:06 139972890150656 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 16 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 1088588 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 838739 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 0

------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2023-10-20 13:57:20 139973168084736
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 44664777, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 11 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 5 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
MySQL thread id 1025545, OS thread handle 139972910249728, query id 100492071 cloudsqlproxy~34.125.160.253 root updating
update AppUser set Address1='919 Conference Drive #4285', AgentPortalAccessToken=null, AgentPortalAccessTokenExpires=null, AgentPortalActive=0, AgentPortalKeySecret=null, AgentPortalLastLoginDateTime=null, AppUserType='NORMAL', AutoDialerPhone=null, BrokerName='', BrokerNum='Dotted & Crossed', City='Goodlettsville', Email1='[.. OMIT ...]', Fax='', FirstName='Paige', ICalFeedAccessKey='[.. OMIT ...]', IsActive=1, LastLoginDateTime='2023-10-20 13:39:49', LastName='Collier', LicenseNum='', LogoFileName='6664cfd4-c435-4c80-b29a-e63853f1fb84.png', Mobile='[.. OMIT ...]', PasswordChangeRequired=0, PasswordHash='[.. OMIT ...]', PasswordResetKey=null, PasswordResetKeyExpires=null, PayableTo='Dotted & Crossed', Phone1='[.. OMIT ...]', ProfileFileName='7dadd45c-9b41-46e9-a944-e740b0c1043e.jpg', RelationshipLeadTime_

*** (1) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 142 page no 1404 n bits 80 index PRIMARY of table `afdata`.`AppUser` trx id 44664777 lock mode S locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 4 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 47; compact format; info bits 0

[.. OMIT ...]

*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 142 page no 1262 n bits 80 index PRIMARY of table `afdata`.`AppUser` trx id 44664777 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 8 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 47; compact format; info bits 0

[.. OMIT ...]

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 44664776, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 70 lock struct(s), heap size 8312, 117 row lock(s), undo log entries 3
MySQL thread id 1025568, OS thread handle 139972994504448, query id 100492103 cloudsqlproxy~34.125.160.253 root updating
update AppUser set Address1='1500 Medical Center Parkway suite 2e', AgentPortalAccessToken='946131', AgentPortalAccessTokenExpires='2023-08-04 15:03:45', AgentPortalActive=1, AgentPortalKeySecret='[.. OMIT ...]', AgentPortalLastLoginDateTime=null, AppUserType='NO_LOGIN', AutoDialerPhone=null, BrokerName='Zach Taylor', BrokerNum='265048', City='Murfreesboro', Email1='[.. OMIT ...]', Fax='', FirstName='Hannah', ICalFeedAccessKey='[.. OMIT ...]', IsActive=1, LastLoginDateTime='2023-08-04 14:53:57', LastName='Mazzaferro', LicenseNum='354478', LogoFileName='b6f94afa-16d8-4e03-a555-38c2ee7df042.png', Mobile='[.. OMIT ...]', PasswordChangeRequired=0, PasswordHash='[.. OMIT ...]', PasswordResetKey=null, PasswordResetKeyExpires=null, PayableTo='Zach Taylor', Phone1='[.. OMIT ...]', ProfileFileName=

[.. OMIT ...]

*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 142 page no 1262 n bits 80 index PRIMARY of table `afdata`.`AppUser` trx id 44664776 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 47; compact format; info bits 0

[.. OMIT ...]

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 142 page no 1404 n bits 80 index PRIMARY of table `afdata`.`AppUser` trx id 44664776 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 4 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 47; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 8000000000002587; asc       % ;;[.. OMIT ...]

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)

[.. OMIT ...]

----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

Comment: `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` can help here. Not sure there's a `FULL` equivalent for the `SHOW STATUS`.

Comment: Please run this query: `SELECT VERSION();` what does it say? Does the version you use include the bug fix from #80927?

Comment: select version() = 8.0.26-google

Comment: SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST just outputs a bunch of rows like: `1071386 root cloudsqlproxy~34.125.129.11 afdata Sleep 1781`